# 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when similar code works

Tags: unity, c#

I am getting an error when accessing a function from `VirtualRotationStick`, despite the fact that a similar `VirtualJoystick` works fine.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   PlayerScript.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Code/PlayerScript.cs:19)

---

Here is my `PlayerScript`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    public VirtualJoyStick DirJoyStick;  
    public VirtualRotationStick RotJoyStick;

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        Vector3 Dir = new Vector3(DirJoyStick.Horz()/10,0,DirJoyStick.Vert()/10);
        float rot = RotJoyStick.Rotation ();
        this.gameObject.transform.position = this.gameObject.transform.position + Dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gnemlock thanks I wasn't 100% sure where the issue was so decided to include both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a public variable in Unity, it makes the variable visible to the Inpector, but it does not give it a valid value. Object types will be initialized to `null`. You have to give it a value by dragging an appropriate component into that slot in the Inspector or you have to initialize the variable yourself (i.e. this.RotJoyStick = new VirtualRotationStick())